# Emphasis in "Why are you making noise"

Tags: emphasis

Is this question ambiguous in what it is asking? i.e. is it asking

- what is your reason for making noise (without considering about other people)?

or

- what is the reason it is you, not another person, who's making the noise?

Comment: Is this really a question about the English?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as written, it is ambiguous. You would apply emphasis when speaking. With no special emphasis, I would assume it means the first thing, "What is your reason for making noise?" But that's because that's a more typical question to ask -- it's not because the *wording* of this question specifically indicates that meaning.

If you want to indicate the second meaning, when speaking, you would almost certainly stress the word **you.** I would probably even stress it in writing, using boldface (as I just did) or something similar.

Comment: There is no ambiguity. Why are **you** making noise? Why are **you** dancing?